# Easy way to concatenate list of strings into a comma-separated strings, where strings are members of an object?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, string, object, string-concatenation

Say I have a List(Of Tag) with Tag being an object.  One member of Tag, Tag.Description, is a string, and I want to make a comma-separated concatenation of the Description members.

Is there an easier way to do this than to read the Description members into a List(Of String) and then use the Join function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
String.Join(", ", tagList.Select(t => t.Description).ToArray());
```

Sorry, I just read again and saw you're using VS2005; so maybe best way is to create a `StringBuilder` and concatenate your `tag.Description`.

Comment: I probably should have put this into the question, but I'm in VS 2005.  My lists don't seem to have a Select method?

Comment: Hah you caught it before I did!  I'll try the StringBuilder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Visual Studio 2005 Solution

```
Public Function ConcatDescription(ByVal list As List(Of Tag) As String
  Dim builder as New StringBuilder
  Dim isFirst As Boolean = True
  For Each t As Tag in list   
    If Not isFirst Then
      builder.Append(","c)
    End If
    builder.Append(t.Description)
    isFirst = False
  Next
  Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```